# DataConnectionDialog dando erro no Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, dll, visual-studio-2017

Estou migrando para o **Visual Studio 2017** um projeto legado que utiliza uma janela modal para coletar dados de conexão ao banco de dados e formatar uma *string* de conexão.

O código abaixo apresenta um erro:

```
var dialog = new DataConnectionDialog();
```

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI,
>   Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f4ca07f51760da93' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=f4ca07f51760da93' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. File name:
>   'Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=f4ca07f51760da93'    at
>   Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI.DataConnectionDialog..ctor()    at
>   Wings4CloudPackage.Forms.frmNewSolution.btnDatabase_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)
>
> === Pre-bind state information === LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=f4ca07f51760da93  (Fully-specified) LOG: Appbase =
>   file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual
>   Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/ LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
>   Calling assembly : Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI.Dialog,
>   Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f4ca07f51760da93.
>   === LOG: This bind starts in LoadFrom load context. WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be
>   probed in default load context, like with Assembly.Load().

Eu já verifiquei o diretório: `C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/` e a dll referenciada (`Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI.dll`) está lá.

O projeto usa o seguinte pacote nuget para exibir a caixa de diálogo: **DataConnectionDialog** (https://www.nuget.org/packages/DataConnectionDialog/1.1.0)

Esse código funciona no **VS2013**, mas não no **VS2017**.

Answer (score 1):

Boas, o pacote que você está utilizando foi retirado do Nuget.

> The owner has unlisted this package. This could mean that the package
>   is deprecated or shouldn't be used anymore.

Utilize este e resolverá seu problema:

> Install-Package com.rusanu.dataconnectiondialog

A sintaxe mudou um pouco nesse pacote:

```
var str = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
var dialog = new DataConnectionDialog(str);
dialog.Show();
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]